# setInverval and delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a div bounce every 4 seconds and after 15 seconds fadeOut. The code bellow makes the div disappear and the bounce doesn't happen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function salta() {
        $('.recomenda').effect("bounce",{ times:4 },300);
    }
    setInterval(salta, 4000);
    $('.recomenda').delay(15000).fadeout('slow');
});
```

This isn't doing the job, any hint you can give me?

Kind regards.

With the help of Matt i figured how to do it:

```
function salta() {
    $('.recomenda').effect("bounce",{ times:4 },300);
}
    var interval = setInterval(salta, 3500);

setTimeout(function (){ 
    clearInterval(interval);
    $('.recomenda').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 15000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit - final version***

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var $recomenda = $('.recomenda');

    function salta()
    {
        $recomenda.effect('bounce', {times:4}, 300);
    }

    salta();
    var interval = setInterval(salta, 4000);

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        // stop the interval from running unnecessarily
        clearInterval(interval);
        $recomenda.fadeOut('slow');
    }, 15000);
});
```

There were 2 other problems:

- `fadeout()` instead of `fadeOut()`
- Using `.delay()` was interfering with the bounce effect

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/a2F3W/

Comment: @Matt Ball, that will make a loop and execute the function again and again, i want the bounce to repeat and after 15 seconds the div will disappear.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. I think the only problem was actually the syntax error.

Comment: I edited my answer - but why was your question using `setInterval` at all if you don't want it to loop?

Comment: I want the bounce animation to loop, after 4 seconds, and after 15 seconds the div must disappear.

Comment: Matt Ball, unfortunately no, there is something wrong with the code :(

Comment: It might be as simple as changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout` but it would help if you could clarify what you mean by "I want the bounce animation to loop, after 4 seconds." What do you mean by "loop?" Do you want the bounce animation to _start_ after 4 seconds?

Comment: @Matt Ball, what i want is, the div to bounce every 4 seconds and after 15 seconds the div will disappear.

Comment: Okay, it's all working now. If you don't want the div to bounce at time = 0, just remove the `salta();` line.

Comment: Matt Ball, the function you gave me didn't work, made some changes (Even though i think it's basically the same) and now it works!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why didn't it work? The jsFiddle appears to work just fine for me.